# How to select a variable and update another variable with that selected variable in single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select top 1 row from a table and update a column of that selected row at the same query. So this is the select query I am using

```
SELECT TOP 1 PageId,
             PageUrl,
             CrawlDepth
FROM   tblPages
WHERE  MainSiteId = 1
       AND UnExpectedCrawlError = 0
       AND CrawlStatus = 0
       AND CrawlingStarted = 0
```

Now this query returns 1 row. What I want is update this to update the `CrawlingStarted` column of this row and set it to 1. So I will select a row and update its 1 column at the same time.

How can I do that?

Comment: See [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an update statement and use an OUTPUT clause.

```
UPDATE TOP (1) t
SET CrawlingStarted = 1
OUTPUT inserted.PageId, inserted.PageUrl, inserted.CrawlDepth
FROM   tblPages t
WHERE  MainSiteId = 1
       AND UnExpectedCrawlError = 0
       AND CrawlStatus = 0
       AND CrawlingStarted = 0
```

Comment: I want to update selected row. With your answer how do i do that ? I am actually asking the ... part

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that requirement. I added a solution for that.

Comment: where is this inserted term coming and thanks for the answer. vote up

Comment: You will find all information about the OUTPUT clause here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx "inserted" is a pseudo table representing the new values.

Comment: Thanks for answer but your query giving error : Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

Comment: Try to vary the position of the from and of the output clause. Wiggle them around until it works ;-) (I had it working in a query window that I already closed).

Comment: Also, the documentation has a lot of examples at the bottom.

Comment: Ok, try again. I added a table alias. This definitely works for me. I just executed it.

Comment: yes problem was you forgot to add table name after set command :) thanks working great.